# JavaEE IDE Eclipse

Tags: java-ee

Boa noite Pessoal eu sou nova no grupo e estou tendo um problema  com meu código alguém poderia me dar uma dica esse é o erro que o sistema está me retornando:

com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Unknown column 'Login' in 'field list'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:526)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3609)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:3541)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2002)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2163)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2624)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2127)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.execute(PreparedStatement.java:1362)
    at br.com.worldinformaticasystemassoftware.jdbc.ClassUsuarioDAO.Cadastrar(ClassUsuarioDAO.java:31)
    at br.com.worldinformaticasystemassoftware.teste.ClassUsuarioTeste.TesteCadastrar(ClassUsuarioTeste.java:27)
    at br.com.worldinformaticasystemassoftware.teste.ClassUsuarioTeste.main(ClassUsuarioTeste.java:10)

Comment: Poderia colocar o código? edite a pergunta e use o botão `{ }` para formata-lo

Comment: ClassUsuarioteste

Comment: Use o link [editar](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/posts/71071/edit) e adicione o(s) método(s) com problema. Aproveite e veja como funciona a estrutura do site na [tour](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/tour)